# Why is my discord bot not going online? node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Ive written out three different pieces of code in Visual Studio Code trying to get my bot online but every time, when i went to cmd and did "node ." or "node index.js" it just went back to the user/desktop/Discordbot>
Here's the code im currently using:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = require ("./token.js");

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.login(token);
```

"token" is stored in a separate file called token.js

Comment: I added code fences to your question to fix the formatting and removed your note about the double "`".

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `require ("./token.js")` with `require("./token.js")`.

Look at your `token.js` file. Make sure it has things inside `module.exports`. Or, you could create a file called `config.json` and create a `token` property and assign it your token, then use `const { token } = require("./config.json");`.

Make sure you also have `Node.js` installed and have ran `npm install discord.js`.

If that doesn't work, please regenerate your token, check that your token is right, check your code, and check any errors in your editor.